# Cloning with DD command

Tags: backup, dd, clone

How can I backup a partition (not the whole disk) to another partition on an external hard-disk using DD?

I achieved this with the following command:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda6 of=/dev/sdb3 bs=1M
```

However my requirements are:

1. I need to backup `/dev/sda6` and store that as an image (`.img`) file in `/dev/sdb3`
2. Preferably as a **compressed (.gz) image file** (this is actually what I am trying to achieve)

(Here are my foolish attempts that, obviously, didn't work:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda6 of=/dev/sdb3/backup.img bs=4096 conv=notrunc,noerror

sudo dd bs=1M if=/dev/sda6 | gzip -c > /dev/sdb3/backup.gz
```

Comment: Do you want to back up the entire partition including unused spaces or just the data in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless `/dev/sdb3` is *actually mounted* on `/dev/sdb3` ( I doubt it, please research a bit on devices and mount points), you'd need to:

1. Find out where `/dev/sdb3` is mounted. Use the `mount` command for this. Assume that `/dev/sdb3` is mounted in `/home`.
2. Point your file writing to that place:

   ```
   sudo dd if=/dev/sda6 of=/home/backup.img
   ```
3. Once done, verify the img file contains what you expect.

Also, is there any need to back up the entire *partition*? I usually find it easier and more useful to back up files using `rsync` or something similar, then if needed compressing the resulting backup directory. But this is really up to you.

Comment: Thank you, roadmr, for your prompt reply (I love this rich community). rsync sounds like a better option. I would be grateful if you could show me how to do this correctly. I will do a little research in the meantime. Thanks again for your time!

Comment: Hi roadmr, thanks to your guidance I could create the backup I wanted. Thanks a lot for helping me!

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do involves 3 simple steps:

1. Creating a disk file
2. Copying data from partition into the disk file
3. Compress the disk file

---

**Creating a disk file**

1. Mount and CD to the partition where you want to keep a disk file
2. Use `fallocate` to create and preallocate blocks to a disk file. It's much faster than creating a file by filling it with zeros using `dd` or other tools. To specify the disk file size you can use `MB/MiB/GB/GiB` prefixes. For example if you want a disk image with size 50 GiB, you do

   `$ fallocate -l 50GiB part_backup.img`
3. Format the disk file. In this example, I use `ext4` and disable journaling feature because there's no need for it in this case

   `$ mkfs.ext4 -O '^has_journal' part_backup.img`
4. Now that we have our disk file ready, mount the disk file with `losetup`. Pass `--show` option to it so it prints the loopback device that your disk file is mounted to, eg `/dev/loop0`

   `$ sudo losetup --show -f part_backup.img`
5. Create a mount folder in `/mnt` and mount the loopback device to the folder

   `$ sudo mount /dev/loop0 /mnt/my_disk_file`

**Copying data from partition into the disk file**

1. Mount the partition that contains files you want to backup and identify the mount point
2. Use `rsync` to copy the files into the disk file you just mounted.

   `$ sudo rsync -avzPSX /mnt/media_partition/ /mnt/my_disk_file`
3. Please look up what each of those rsync opts does in rsync man if you're unusure. Also read the note about trailing slash in backup source

**Compress the disk file**

1. Unmount the disk file as per normal

   `$ sudo umount /mnt/my_disk_file`
   `$ sudo losetup -d /dev/loop0`
2. Use `gzip` to compress the disk file

Comment: I will definitely try this out and ask for help if I need. Thanks a lot for your time!