# can dd be used with an external hdd to clone the image on a new system?

Tags: boot, hard-drive, external-hdd, dd, clone

I think I asked that right, but here goes.

I have 2 systems A and B. A has failed. I want to clone B and install it on A.

Can I use dd to make a clone of B, put that clone on an external HDD to transfer and install on A? or does dd simply turn the external HDD into a bootable copy of B?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cloning with DD command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461193/cloning-with-dd-command)

Comment: Can you not use a Live USB to directly clone B to A without using the USB disk? You can backup B to the USB using dd or Disks and restore it to A but why take the extra step?